# How to unit test location services pop up in Android

Tags: android, testing, kotlin, junit, expresso

I'm really trying to wrap  my head  around unit testing.   Could use a  little help for a  road block. I'm  trying  to click the location popup buttons when asking  for location  permissions.
I'm using JUnit 4 and expresso.
Here's my test rule:

```
@get:Rule
val testRule: ActivityTestRule<MyActivity> = ActivityTestRule(MyActivity::class.java)
```

I got a set up function:

```
@Before
fun setUp() {
    mActivity = testRule.activity
    mFragment = MyFragment.newInstance()
}
```

And finally my button click  test:

```
@Test
fun testLocationClick(){
    Assert.assertNotNull(onView(withId(R.id.button_turn_on_location)))
    onView(withId(R.id.button_turn_on_location)).perform(click())

    onView(withText("Allow all")).perform(click())
```

This last line  saying "Allow  all" was my attempt to try and click on the allow button but  it  does  not  work. Here's an attached image showing what I'm  trying to click.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBUbe.png)

Answer (score 1):

Shameless self-plug: I wrote an article describing a solution to a similar problem back in 2016 called [Testing Runtime Permissions: Lessons Learned](https://blog.egorand.me/testing-runtime-permissions-lessons-learned/), hope it's still useful. TLDR: since the permission dialog is a system dialog and lives outside of your app's process, it's not reachable with Espresso. You'd need to use the [UI Automator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator), which offers more possibilities in terms of accessing system UI from under test.

Comment: Thank you so much! Will look into it :)